# Wordpress Plugins on a website designed in HTML CSS

Tags: wordpress

I designed a website in pure HTML, CSS and JS. Is it possible to import that website to wordpress and then add the wordpress plugins to it?

Answer (score 1):

You want to integrate the HTML code in WordPress theme. [see reference](https://websitesetup.org/html-to-wordpress/)